# Unable to launch Chrome using Selenium on Mac

Tags: java, selenium

I've created a simple class to launch chrome and getting below on terminal. Please help

Is it something releated to Run Configuration or Chrome driver or Selenium??

Thanks

---------------------output on terminal---------------------------------

```
utun0
   address.getHostName() = fe80:0:0:0:913a:9964:17c6:7e52%utun0
   address.getHostAddress() = fe80:0:0:0:913a:9964:17c6:7e52%utun0
   address.isLoopbackAddress() = false
awdl0
   address.getHostName() = fe80:0:0:0:945c:94ff:feb0:86a%awdl0
   address.getHostAddress() = fe80:0:0:0:945c:94ff:feb0:86a%awdl0
   address.isLoopbackAddress() = false
en0
   address.getHostName() = 2a02:c7d:e291:e600:50d0:d083:9852:f961%en0
   address.getHostAddress() = 2a02:c7d:e291:e600:50d0:d083:9852:f961%en0
   address.isLoopbackAddress() = false
   address.getHostName() = 2a02:c7d:e291:e600:1843:bc63:8c3d:c266%en0
   address.getHostAddress() = 2a02:c7d:e291:e600:1843:bc63:8c3d:c266%en0
   address.isLoopbackAddress() = false
   address.getHostName() = fd1a:d88c:5538:0:4cfc:4f03:a79e:6e8c%en0
   address.getHostAddress() = fd1a:d88c:5538:0:4cfc:4f03:a79e:6e8c%en0
   address.isLoopbackAddress() = false
   address.getHostName() = fd1a:d88c:5538:0:1cb2:a9ed:441d:5d61%en0
   address.getHostAddress() = fd1a:d88c:5538:0:1cb2:a9ed:441d:5d61%en0
   address.isLoopbackAddress() = false
   address.getHostName() = fe80:0:0:0:ca7:8010:3bdf:211d%en0
   address.getHostAddress() = fe80:0:0:0:ca7:8010:3bdf:211d%en0
   address.isLoopbackAddress() = false
   address.getHostName() = nileshs-mbp
   address.getHostAddress() = 192.168.0.57
   address.isLoopbackAddress() = false
lo0
   address.getHostName() = fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0
   address.getHostAddress() = fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0
   address.isLoopbackAddress() = false
   address.getHostName() = localhost
   address.getHostAddress() = 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0
   address.isLoopbackAddress() = true
   address.getHostName() = localhost
   address.getHostAddress() = 127.0.0.1
   address.isLoopbackAddress() = true
Loopback interface LO:
lo0
   address.getHostName() = fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0
   address.getHostAddress() = fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0
   address.isLoopbackAddress() = false
   address.getHostName() = localhost
   address.getHostAddress() = 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0
   address.isLoopbackAddress() = true
   address.getHostName() = localhost
   address.getHostAddress() = 127.0.0.1
   address.isLoopbackAddress() = true
```

Comment: Check your `/etc/host` file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you please provide more details on what the issue is and what do I need to check for?

Comment: Below are the contents of host file
--------------------------------------------------
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost